# how to pass a custom object to controller using JSON

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I am trying to send User object to my REST api in json format.

```
var user={
firstName: "someVal",lastName: "", email: "", contactPhone: "", password: "" 
};
var url="http://localhost:8085/MyappName/appliPath/login";
$.ajax({
method:'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
datatype:'json',
url : url,
data:JSON.stringify(user),
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
},
error: function(error){
  console.log(error);
}
});
});
```

Following is my login controller class code

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static User register(User user){
    System.out.println("in register");
    User register = null;
    if(!validateUser(user.getEmail())){
        System.out.println("calling new user");
        register = loginDao.addNewUser(user);
        System.out.println("returning user");
    }
    return register;
}
```

how shall I send complex user to my code? shall I say `@Path("{user}")` ?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Are you getting errors? If so what? That information will help use help you.... And don't make the method `static`

Answer (score 1):

HI You can send complex Object using Post method to your Rest API.
Below is the REST API that will accept the User JOSN object.
You can Follow more about how to post Complex Object here:http://entityclass.in/rest/jerseyClientGetXml.htm

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/StudentService")
public class StudentService {

    @POST
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJOSN( User user ) {

        User output = user.toString();

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

For this RestFull API i have written JAVA client

```
public class ClientJerseyPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            User user = new User();
            user.setName("JON");
            user.setAddress("Paris");
            user.setId(5);

            String resturl = "http://localhost:8080/RestJerseyClientXML/rest/StudentService/update";
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(resturl);

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, student);
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);



            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```